# google-fluentd error on debian stretch (Google Logging Agent)

Tags: debian, google-cloud-platform, fluentd, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-kubernetes-engine

After upgrading my docker image from **php:7.1.11-apache** to **php:7.2.0-apache** (FROM debian:stretch-slim) **google-fluentd** package is not found / installed.

This is the output when I try to build the docker image in GKE installing google fluentd (https://dl.google.com/cloudagents/install-logging-agent.sh) :

```
W: GPG error: http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt google-cloud-logging-wheezy InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 3746C208A7317B0F
W: The repository 'http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt google-cloud-logging-wheezy InRelease' is not signed.
```

And running the container image I get this error (because it's not installed):

```
/bin/sh: 1: /etc/init.d/google-fluentd: not found
```

Following the guide https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/installation I see support to Debian 8.

Do you know any workaround or fix to solve this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/fluent-plugin-google-cloud/issues/199

Answer (score 0):

add apt-key first

```
curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key --keyring /usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg add -
```